# font adds top padding

Tags: html, css

at the most basic level with just

```
 <span style="border: solid 1px #000; font-size: 70px">z</span>
```

the z is nicely aligned in the middle of the box vertically

http://jsfiddle.net/zszpaduj/

but once I start applying a font such as

```
 body {
      font-family: Arial;
 }
```

the z gets padded from the top a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/zszpaduj/1/

I've even used

```
 * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
 }
```

Added space is still there

http://jsfiddle.net/zszpaduj/2/

What's causing this?

I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference in the padding when I run it on my browser (I'm running Chrome  40.0.2214.115 on Windows).

It is however, worth knowing that padding rules for top and bottom apply correctly only to block elements (like a `div`), but not for inline elements (like a `span`). You can add padding to the top and bottom of an inline element, but it won't affect the spacing of the other inline elements around it, so the padding will overwrap other inline elements.

As an example, copy paste the code below in a file and and open it in Chrome.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      span {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        font-size: 70px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 40px 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>I'm</span><span>a</span><br>
    <span>legend</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bottom line - Padding rules for top and bottom may not give the result you desire for inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<span style="border: solid 1px #000; font-size: 70px; height: 70px; line-height: 60px;">z</span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 font-family: arial;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/confile/zszpaduj/3/